# Can a judgment from a parent that is deceased be transferred to a family member?

Tags: california, rules-of-court

A parent (plaintiff) received a judgement in California (Superior Court) and is now deceased. Is it possible to transfer this judgement to the family of the plaintiff or a member of the plaintiff's family? If so, how would this be done?

Evidently, the defendant stopped making monthly payments once the plaintiff was deceased.

Answer (score 1):

### The judgement is an asset of the estate

The executor can approach the court to have it enforced until the estate is would up.

As an asset, it must be dealt with in accordance with the will and bequeathed as instructed. This will involve approaching the court and having the judgement debt transferred to the relevant beneficiaries or keeping the estate active until the debt has run its course.

Comment: Mechanically, the transfer would be done with a written assignment document signed by the executor. I recently prepared one for a client.